# I want to use Jquery to live swap input field names

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a webpage where I am using Jquery to add form fields dynamically and all is well.  Below is a sample of how the fields are named.  Basically when the user wants more fields then they hit a button and it inserts the two fields and increments the values of the next inputs and creates a container div surrounding the fields.

```
<fieldset id="dynamicField">
<div id="fieldID1"><ul><li> 
<label for="headertext_1">Header Text</label>
<input id="headertext_1" name="headertext_1" size="70" value="My Header Text" />
</li>
<li>
<label for="blurblink_1">Link</label>
<input id="blurblink_1" name="blurblink_1" value="http://foo.bar" size="70" />
</li></ul></div>

<div id="fieldID2"><ul><li> 
<label for="headertext_2">Header Text</label>
<input id="headertext_2" name="headertext_2" size="70" value="My Next Header Text" />
</li>
<li>
<label for="blurblink_2">Link</label>
<input id="blurblink_2" name="blurblink_2" value="http://bar.foo" size="70" />
</li></ul></div></fieldset>
```

Okay, so now what I need to add is a way for these fieldsIDs to be reordered - not only on the page, that would be easy enough, but I also need to rename the field names so that my backend server processing still works.

So for example:

If I have 1,2,3,4,5 different group of fields on the page I want to be able to click a few buttons to move 5 to this order on the screen and named correctly as well:

1,5,2,3,4

Thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by "*named correctly as well*"? What HTML should result if the order is changed as you show?

Comment: I am coming back to this project.  At one point I think I was swapping out input names and that renaming of input fields wasn't recognized on the server side.  I am not a jQuery pro, but maybe that has something to do with live?

Comment: And that doesn't answer the question I asked, I'm not a pro myself, just a hobbyist; but once you start it's not so hard to learn.